# Why does the array use the '===' operator to compare elements?

Tags: ios, swift

From the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ClassesAndStructures.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH13-XID_109) about arrays:

> Check whether two arrays or subarrays share the same storage and elements by comparing them with the identity operators (=== and !==)

However, to check if two arrays contain the same elements, wouldn't you use the comparison operator `==` (because you're comparing the values of the array) instead of the identity `===` (which would check if you are referring to the same array)?

Assuming I am understanding the operators properly, is this behaviour caused by array's implementation as a `struct`?

Answer (score 2):

The key word there is "storage" - that means they are one and the same "object", which is indeed identity.

And this check is needed because arrays are copied by reference rather than by value, so you can fall into the trap of altering "another" array if you're not careful - which is what this section of the guide is about.

Comment: Actually @Timidger has a point. === should return false to be consistent when we have different references

Comment: The interesting part: `var a = [1,2,3], b = a, c = a;` Then `b === c` is **false**, but `b[0...2] === c[0...2]` is **true**.

Comment: @akashivskyy even more: now try `c.unshare()` - the arrays are now `==` but the slices are not

Comment: @akashivskyy Even weirder, the slices are not `==` but arrays made from them (e.g. `Array(b[0...2])`) are `==`